# Accessing option value

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using PHP to list all sub-directories in gallery folder:

```
<div class="dropdown-gallery" id="dropdown-gallery" onchange="changeGallery(this)">
  <select>
    <?php
       $galleries = scandir("./gallery");
       foreach($galleries as $gallery){
           echo("<option value='$gallery'>$gallery</option> ");
       }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

I would like to operate on values of those optinos in JS, the problem is that this code:

```
function changeGallery(elem){
    alert(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value);
    alert(elem.value);
}
```

Returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined in both alert cases 
I was looking for a solution and found nothing that could help me

Comment: You're working with DIV instead of input select, DIVs has no options or value attributes. Wich library are you using for your styled select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're listening for the `onchange` event on a `div`, so `this` is the `div` and not the `select`.

`div` elements don't have `options`.

Move the event listener to the `<select>` element.

---

If you really want to bind the handler to the div and do delegated event handling (which can be useful if you have multiple select elements or are adding some with JS) then use the `target` property of the event to identify the select element.

```js
document
    .querySelector('.dropdown-gallery')
    .addEventListener('change', event => console.log(event.target.value))
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-gallery">
  <select>
     <option>1
     <option>2
     <option>3
  </select>
  
    <select>
     <option>4
     <option>5
     <option>6
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the handler `onchange="changeGallery(this)"` on the `<select>` not the `<div>`

Answer (score -1):

```js
function selectChanged(ev, el){
    alert(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="selectChanged(event, this)">
  <option value="">Select A Value</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```